# How to avoid "no return" warning in Dart when there is a return statement in "switch-case"?

Tags: dart, switch-statement

I created an enum representing different possible intervals:

`enum Interval { day, week, month, year }`

In a method _changePeriod I covered every case possible, but I still receive warning that "This function has a return type of 'DateRange', but doesn't end with a return statement."

```
DateRange _changePeriod(DateRange range, int change) {
    DateTime newMoment = change == -1
        ? range.startHour.subtract(Duration(hours: 1))
        : range.finalHour.add(Duration(hours: 1));

    switch (range.interval) {
      case Interval.day:
        {
          return DateRange.day(newMoment);
        }
      case Interval.week:
        {
          return DateRange.week(newMoment);
        }
      case Interval.month:
        {
          return DateRange.month(newMoment);
        }
      case Interval.year:
        {
          return DateRange.year(newMoment);
        }
    }
  }
```

I know that this is "just" a warning, but is there any option to write better code an correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35710.  It will be fixed with Dart's upcoming null-safety improvements (expected when Dart 2.12 becomes stable). Before null-safety, the analyzer cannot tell that the `switch` expression can never be null, and it therefore cannot conclude that code after the `switch` block is unreachable.

In the meantime, since code after the `switch` statement should be logically unreachable (assuming that the `switch` expression shouldn't ever be `null`), I'd just `throw` an error:

```dart
DateRange _changePeriod(DateRange range, int change) {
  ...

  switch (range.interval) {
    case Interval.day:
      return DateRange.day(newMoment);
    case Interval.week:
      return DateRange.week(newMoment);
    case Interval.month:
      return DateRange.month(newMoment);
    case Interval.year:
      return DateRange.year(newMoment);
  }
  throw AssertionError('Unknown interval: ${range.interval}');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either add a `default` statement and add a `return`, or `return` a default value after the switch is over:

Method 1:

```
DateRange _changePeriod(DateRange range, int change) {
  DateTime newMoment = change == -1
      ? range.startHour.subtract(Duration(hours: 1))
      : range.finalHour.add(Duration(hours: 1));

  switch (range.interval) {
    case Interval.day:
      return DateRange.day(newMoment);
    case Interval.week:
      return DateRange.week(newMoment);
    case Interval.month:
      return DateRange.month(newMoment);
    case Interval.year:
      return DateRange.year(newMoment);
    default:
      return null; // or some value
  }
}
```

Method 2:

```
DateRange _changePeriod(DateRange range, int change) {
  DateTime newMoment = change == -1
      ? range.startHour.subtract(Duration(hours: 1))
      : range.finalHour.add(Duration(hours: 1));

  switch (range.interval) {
    case Interval.day:
      return DateRange.day(newMoment);
    case Interval.week:
      return DateRange.week(newMoment);
    case Interval.month:
      return DateRange.month(newMoment);
    case Interval.year:
      return DateRange.year(newMoment);
  }
  return null; // or some value
}
```

Another way is when you are handling an `enum` case, you can make sure to check all the possible values in each `case` for that particular `enum`.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore True. Though, these 2 cases also extend to non-enum cases. I will add that case to the answer though, thank you

Comment: I do not recommend adding a `default:` case since that would undermine the [`exhaustive_cases` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/exhaustive_cases.html) if a new `enum` value were added.

Comment: In OP's example, all the enum values were already used. I'm not sure why they got the lint in the first place...

Comment: The OP is getting a `missing_return` warning; that's separate from `exhaustive_cases`. See my answer.